# Angular 4 http post to Java SpringMVC; POST parameters not seen

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, angular, spring-mvc

I am working on a REST api in Java Maven Spring boot SpringMVC. Angular POST request parameters are not being seen by SpringMVC @RequestParam. Here is the Angular code;

```
  saveAsSiteProduct(id: number, data: saveAsSiteProductSettings): Observable<any> {
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) });
    return this.http
      .post(this.amazonUrl + '/products/imported/' + id +'/saveas/siteproduct', JSON.stringify(data), options)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

And here is the Java SpringMVC code;

```
@PostMapping(value = "/products/imported/{id}/saveas/siteproduct", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<CustomHttpResponse> saveAsSiteProduct(
            @PathVariable Long id,
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams,
            @RequestParam("guid") String guid
            ) throws EncoderException, RestClientException {
...
}
```

But I am getting the response;

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-10-02T21:21:58.064+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
    "message": "Required String parameter 'guid' is not present",
    "path": "/api/amazon/products/imported/1/saveas/siteproduct"
}
```

This is what I am posting;

```
{
createBrandIfNotExists : true
createManufacturerIfNotExists : true
guid : "asD"
}
```

I have tested this in Postman and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `URLSearchParams` instead and changed the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Here is how I have done it;

```
  saveAsSiteProduct(id: number, data: saveAsSiteProductSettings): Observable<any> {
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) });
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    for (var key in data) {
      params.set(key, data[key]);
    }
    return this.http
      .post(this.amazonUrl + '/products/imported/' + id +'/saveas/siteproduct', params, options)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
```